# Differential equation $\csc(y)\frac{dy}{dx}=(y-1)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have given a question in which

> $$\displaystyle\csc(y)\frac{dy}{dx}=(y-1)$$
>   with initial condition $\displaystyle y(\frac{\pi}{2})=k$,$k \in \bf{R}$ then
>
> $1).$ if $k<1$ when $y(x)$ is decreasing and $\lim_{n\to \infty}y(x)=0$
>
> $2).$ if $k>1$ then $y(x)$ is increasing and bounded
>
> $3).$ $y(x)$ is bounded always
>
> $4).$ $S=\left \{k \in \bf{R} : y(x)\ \text{is constant} \right \} $ is countable